# Why Chrome alerts are showing multiple times? (the same alert)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, alert

I'm doing a personal Chrome extension that gets data from a specific collection from Firebase and shows it as a browser alert, in my case, a Chrome alert.
My problem is that when I get to show the alert it shows up multiple times. In the next images is "just" showing two times, but in other cases I even received four consecutive times the same alert:[first alert that shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq8T1.jpg), [the alert that is shown when I "OK" the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbyCP.jpg)

And I also noticed that the alert I receive is not on the same position as other examples I found searching, [like this one from w3schools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmQv5.png)

Here's the code I'm using to invoque the alert:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

var db = firebase.firestore();
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
let url_f = tabs[0].url;

url_f = url_f.replaceAll("/", ",")

var docRef = db.collection("URL").doc(url_f);
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {

      window.alert(JSON.stringify(doc.data()))

    } else {
        //pass
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
  //Error getting document:",error
  resp({type: "result", status: "error", data: error, request: msg});
}) }) })
```

(*The last two "})" are well indented at my script, but when I copied here it moved*)
As you will notice, the alert is expected to show everytime a pre-saved URL at the Firebase collection is opened at the browser, (The "/" from the URL's are changed to "," so I can compare it with the ones saved in Firebase, because it doesn't allow to save documents with "/" in the name)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you add console.log(changeInfo) you will see this event is called a lot for each tab so you need to filter those updates, like `if (!changeInfo.url) return;` Also, why are you always getting the active tab? Inactive tabs can also update so remove the call to query() and simply use `changeInfo.url || tab.url`

Comment: And for what exactly is "changeInfo" used to??

Comment: See the documentation of course.

Comment: Let's go! Thanks, the solution was as you said to include the "if (!changeInfo.url) return;"